# importing a cloned git project in eclipse results in some modified files

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github, git-clone

Hello everyone i am experiencing a strange issue where i am cloning a project from github repository and then trying to import it into eclipse. The problem that arises when i import the cloned project is that when i run git status command i get your branch is up to date with origin/master yet i see some files marked as modified under the messgae

Changes not staged for commit:
   modified://some files.
   modified://some files.
Untracked files:
  pathtosomefile/.gitignore

Background: I am shifting my work from one pc to another(laptop). Both have windows 10 installed, the original project was created and pushed to git using eclipse version Neon while the laptop in which i am shifting my work has eclipse photon installed. Apart from that environment is completely identical.

Also Note that when i just do git clone and check git status i get no modified files message just the message your branch is up to date with master/origin which is correct since i am just cloning and haven't changed a file.

Comment: Which type of files are those ? Screenshot will help.

Comment: @NinadPingale the files are .class files

Comment: So .class files are also pushed to git ? those are getting modified once you compile in your eclipse.

Comment: @NinadPingale but not all classfiles are being stated as modified only few of them are being reported as modified??

Comment: @NinadPingale can you please explain more clearly the point about compilation

Comment: It is recommended to commit only `.java` files and not `.class` files into a Git repository. The [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode) (`.class` files) differs when you compile it with a different Java version (because the version is included in the header), but can also differ when using a different version of a compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make sure that your `.gitignore` file is correctly maintained as no class files should be on git. If you are getting issue with cloning with cmd you can use the internal eclipse way to import project

Do the following

1. Open Eclipse
2. Click on file
3. Click import
4. Type GIT
5. Select projects from GIT
6. provide clone URI with al desired details like password or token if any.

Then this way there should be no issue.

Comment with URL if this is not the solution for you and I can do that quickly for you.

Comment: I have removed the [SPAM](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) part from the answer. Please do not recommend your favorite tool if you were not asked and it is not relevant to answer the question as in this case (even though you like it very much and/or paid money for it). To the remaining main part of the answer: why should the (re)import solve the problem?